# LocationService or LocationThread?

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I am am coding an application which has to record both datas from a device (via BlueTooth) and location every second.

For now, the data recording works with : one activity, which displays the datas, one remote service, which handles the bluetooth connection and the recording in a textfile. The loop of 1 second which requests and receives datas is in a Thread, started from the remote service.

Now I have to make a request from my loopThread to get the current location.

My question is : what should I use to update the location? Another remote service or another Thread in my first remote service?

What are the arguments for and against each one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use same thread or service as well and different service and thread too but always keep in mind that receiving location data from provider is asynchronous so I would suggest go with same thread or service 
because creating one more service will consume more memory and when you are developing for mobile you should always try to use less memory

Comment: What I would like to do is refreshing the current location in a different Thread or service, register it in a Location variable, for example 'myLocation'. Then, when the loopThread needs it, it throws a message via handler and requests 'myLocation', which can be the same as last time or can have changed 3 times without being used.

I really need this app to be accurate, and the power consummation comes second.

What I would like to know is if there is a difference between the execution of a remote service and of a Thread, which could lead me to choose one or the other